# Mapping 404s to a URL when I also have a Servlet at /

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I want to catch 404 errors in my Tomcat 7 applicaion so I added this to web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

This works fine except for when I have a servlet mapped to the root "/" URL, if I have a homepage servlet such as:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Home", urlPatterns =
{
    "/"
})
```

Then when I navigate to an invalid URL I get taken to the homepage "/" rather than /404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` URL pattern does not represent the "home page". It is a special URL pattern which matches **everything** which is *not* matched by the more specific URL patterns such as `*.jsp`, `/app/*`, etc.

If you use this URL pattern on a servlet, then it will become the so-called "default servlet" where **all** requests would end up when there's no other servlet listening on the URL pattern. This also includes static resources like CSS/JS/image files. Normally, the default servlet is already provided out the box by the servletcontainer itself (in your case with Tomcat, it's the [`DefaultServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html)).

Generally, you're not supposed to use an URL pattern of `/`. In order to achieve your concrete functional requirement of having a servlet as "home page", your best bet is to give the servlet a more specific URL pattern and register exactly that servlet as `<welcome-file>`.

E.g.

```
@WebServlet("/index")
```

with

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```